# Wygwam+Safecracker: long URL gets limited to 60 characters and breaks HTML

Tags: safecracker, wygwam

Real URLs have been changed to protect the innocent, but the dummy URLs are the exact same length (197 characters unexpectedly truncated to 60) and similar format. When posting this to a Wygwam field **via Safecracker but not from the control panel** ...

```
 <p>This is oddly frustrating. <a href="http://foo.com/content/page/index.phtml?a=ca1ca56e8338eba3c6fe9a3c182811e4&b=329040bdfc813321bb314de480cd4c2f&c=ca1ca56e8338eba3c6fe9a3c182811e4&d=ca1ca56e8338eba3c6fe9a3c182811e4&e=ca1ca56e8338eb">Here's the link</a>. This sentence should come after the link.</p>
```

... the result ends up being stored like this ...

```
 <p>This is oddly frustrating. <a href="http://foo.com/content/page/index.phtml?a=ca1ca56e8338eba3c>Here's the link</a>. This sentence should come after the link.</p>
```

Notice that the href property is never completed with a `"` even despite the truncated URL.

Why would this happen via Safecracker and *not* via the control panel?

EE 2.6.1, Wygwam 3.1.2.

Comment: I'd report this as a bug to EE.

Comment: Done! I'll update this question if there turns out to be a definitive answer.